# resnet-binary model in BMXnet to train my own data, but get float weights not binary weights

Tags: python-3.x, mxnet, resnet

I have used the resnet-binary model in BMXnet to train my own data, but get float weights not binary weights. Why?

**The parameter of the network**

[image]

**Load the trained model and use `model.get_params()`**

[image]

Comment: Please do not add any output as linked images. Add the text directly to your question, with an indentation of 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are steps necessary to binarize the model. See that project's repo: https://github.com/hpi-xnor/BMXNet

You may get more specialized assistance by posting in the issues tab of that repo.